# Express server and serving dynamically changed values

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, server

I'm using express for my node app and I want to access a variable via XMLHttpRequest. The variable on the server keeps changing between true and false every 10 seconds so I can test changes.
How do I make the value update? Changing the variable manually and restarting the server works but I need it to update live.

I also want to send a request that will fetch the variable on my client side:
Something like this:

```
var xhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
var url = "someUrl"

xhttp.open("GET", "url", true);
xhttp.send();
```

I know this might be a badly structured question but I hope I was descriptive enough to get my point and question across. I'm fairly new with express and I don't fully understand it well yet.
Is this even possible?

Edit: + server code

```
var app = require('express')();
var http = require('http').Server(app);
var io = require('socket.io')(http);
var port = process.env.PORT || 8030;



app.get('/control', function (req, res) {
    res.sendFile(__dirname + '/control.html');
});

app.get('/peer', function (req, res) {
    res.sendFile(__dirname + '/peer.html');
});

app.get('/client', function (req, res) {
    res.sendFile(__dirname + '/client.html');
});

app.get('/socket.io', function (req, res) {
    res.sendFile(__dirname + '/socket.io.js');
});

app.get('/simplepeer', function (req, res) {
    res.sendFile(__dirname + '/simplepeer.js');
});

app.get('/hls', function (req, res) {
    res.sendFile(__dirname + '/hls.js');
});

app.get('/blob-stream', function (req, res) {
    res.sendFile(__dirname + '/blob-stream.js');
});

app.get('/buffer', function (req, res) {
    res.sendFile(__dirname + '/buffer.js');
});

var thisThing = true;

function refreshData() {
    x = 5;
    console.log(x)
    setTimeout(refreshData, x * 1000);

    if (thisThing) {

        thisThing = false;

        app.get('/response', function (req, res) {
            res.send('id:1');


        });
console.log(thisThing)

    } else {

        thisThing = true;

        app.get('/response', function (req, res) {
            res.send('id:2');

        });
        console.log(thisThing)

    }

}


refreshData();
```

Comment: you need to have a server endpoint at your `express` server which will return your variable

Comment: please post your server code

Comment: Added server code. 
Not sure if that's the proper way to do this.

Comment: Also, should the url in my request be just the address: "http://localhost:8030/response"?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

change your endpoint like so:

```
var myChangingNumber = 0

setInterval(function() {
  myChangingNumber++
}, 1000);

app.get('/response', function (req, res) {
    res.send(myChangingNumber);
});
```

i added this `jsfiddle` to demonstrate the technique behind. Hope this is what you were asking for.

https://jsfiddle.net/o8qhynkj/

fiddle code:

```js
var x = 0;
setInterval(function() {
   console.log(x)
}, 1000);
setInterval(function() {
   x++
}, 1000);
```

**NOTE:** this is an infinite loop ;)

Comment: Invalid status code: 2
    at ServerResponse.writeHead (_http_server.js:190:11)
    at ServerResponse._implicitHeader (_http_server.js:181:8)
    at ServerResponse.end (_http_outgoing.js:757:10)

Comment: did you remove the duplicate implementations?  how does your `/response` endpoint look like now?

Comment: There are no duplicate implementations and I just get different errors when I use different methods. I might need to do a bit of research by myself since I'm not sure this is even possible.